# What does [@] mean in bash?

Tags: bash, directory

I have the following legacy script which moves entire files into a build directory. It is moving all the `.js` files but it is not moving any of the `.py` ending files. If a dir contain a `.js` ending file it will only move that file, if the dir doesn't contain any `.js` file it will not move anything. I think I need to modify the `${files[@]}` part to include `.py` files. Can somebody tell me what does `"${files[@]}"` mean ? Or better how to include moving `.py` ending files.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
dirs=("app")
files=("server.js")

function compile-dir {
    babel $1 --out-dir "./build/$1"
}

function compile-file {
    babel $1 --out-dir "./build"
}

rm -rf ./build

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    compile-dir "$dir"
done

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    compile-file $file
done

mkdir "./build/resources"
cp -R "./resources/" "./build/"
cp -R "./config" "./build/"
```

Comment: One way to find answers to questions like this is by searching through [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). In this case, `files` is an array, and `foo "${files[@]}"` simply expands to `foo "file1" "file2" "file3"...`.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Comment: @Shawn I see now, but still don't get how it included all the files but not any `.py` files. and `files=("server.js")`

Comment: You should look into whatever that `babel` program is.

Comment: @Shawn got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly address your question: `"What does [@] mean in bash?"` the `[@]` is used in combination with an array variable to expand all elements within that array. Here are some bash/python equivalencies

#### Bash

```sh
# Declare array
array=("e1" "e2" "e3")

# Print array one line
echo ${array[@]}

# Iterate over array elements
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $element
done
```

#### Python

```py
# Declare array
array=["e1", "e2", "e3"]

# Print array one line
print(array)

# Iterate over array elements
for element in array:
    print(element)
```

More generally though, you seem to be having trouble understanding this legacy bash script you've inherited. Here it is marked up with some comments.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
# This script uses the babel compiler to compile a list of directories
# and files. To use this script properly make sure to populate
# the 'dirs' and 'files' arrays below before running

# Manage directories/files in two arrays
dirs=("app")
files=("server.js")

# compile-dir
# Use babel to compile a direcotry and output it into the build dir
# @param <dirname>
function compile-dir {
    babel $1 --out-dir "./build/$1"
}

# compile-file
# Use babel to compile a file and output it into the build dir
# @param <filename>
function compile-file {
    babel $1 --out-dir "./build"
}

#################################
#         -- MAIN --            #
#################################

# Begin by deleting the existing build dir
rm -rf ./build

# Compile all dirs in dirs array
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    compile-dir "$dir"
done

# Compile all files in files array
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    compile-file $file
done

# Move 'resources' and 'config' dirs into 'resources' subdir of './build'
mkdir "./build/resources"
cp -R "./resources/" "./build/"
cp -R "./config" "./build/"
```